# Switching from tf.nn.* to tf.layers.* ruined the model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was exploring TensorFlow modules with convnet on notMNIST [Assignment 4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/4_convolutions.ipynb) from the Udacity Deep Learning course.

My initial model uses `tf.nn.conv2d` and `tf.nn.max_pool` and provides validation accuracy of around 90%

**Initial model, `tf.nn.*`**

```
batch_size = 32
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64
seed=4242

tf.reset_default_graph()

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

    # Input data.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)


    def conv_relu_maxpool(inputs, kernel_shape, bias_shape, bias_init_v=0.0):
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights", shape = kernel_shape,
                                 initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed))
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases", shape = bias_shape,
                                initializer = tf.constant_initializer(bias_init_v))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, weights, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + biases)
        maxpool = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, [1,2,2,1], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')

        return maxpool


    def dense(inputs, units, activation=None):
        return tf.layers.dense(
            inputs,
            units=units,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05, seed=seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
            name="Dense"
        )


    # Model.
    def model(data, keep_prob=1):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
            layer1 = conv_relu_maxpool(data, [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], [depth], 0.01)

        with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
            layer2 = conv_relu_maxpool(layer1, [patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], [depth], 1.0)
        shape = layer2.get_shape().as_list()
        reshape = tf.reshape(layer2, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

        with tf.variable_scope("dense1"):
            dense1 = dense( reshape, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout( dense1, keep_prob=keep_prob, seed=seed)
        with tf.variable_scope("dense2"):
            dense2 = dense( dense1, 32, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout( dense2, keep_prob=keep_prob, seed=seed)
        with tf.variable_scope("dense3"):
            dense3 = dense( dropout2, num_labels)

        return dense3


    with tf.variable_scope("model"):
        # Training computation.
        logits = model(tf_train_dataset, keep_prob=0.7)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))

        # Optimizer.
        global_step = tf.Variable(0)  # count the number of steps taken.
        learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.05, global_step, 1001, 0.8)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

        # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
        train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
        valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
        test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))
```

I rewrote it to `tf.layers.conv2d` and `tf.layers.max_pooling2d` followed by `tf.layers.dense` and `tf.layers.dropout`.  Now the model fails to train, runs too fast and gives 10% (random choice) validation accuracy. Cannot figure out what's the cause.

**The graph:**

```
batch_size = 32
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64
seed=4242

graph = tf.Graph()
tf.reset_default_graph()
with graph.as_default():

    # Input data.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)


    # Model.
    def model(data, keep_prob=0.5, training=False):
        conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
            data, filters=depth, kernel_size=1, padding='SAME',
            activation=tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
            name="Conv_1"
        )
        pool_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d( conv_1, pool_size=patch_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')

        conv_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
            pool_1, filters=depth, kernel_size=1, padding='SAME',
            activation=tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=2*seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0),
            name="Conv_2"
        )
        pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d( conv_2, pool_size=patch_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')

        shape = pool_2.get_shape().as_list()
        reshape = tf.reshape(pool_2, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

        dense_1 = tf.layers.dense(
            reshape, units=num_hidden, activation=tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0)
        )

        dropout_1 = tf.layers.dropout( dense_1, rate=(1.0-keep_prob), seed=seed, training=training)

        dense_2 = tf.layers.dense(
            dropout_1, units=num_labels, activation=None,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0)
        )

        return dense_2


    with tf.variable_scope("model"):
        # Training computation.
        logits = model(tf_train_dataset, training=True)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))

        # Optimizer.
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="globalStep", trainable=False)  # count the number of steps taken.
        learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.05, global_step, 1001, 0.8)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

        # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
        train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
        valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
        test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))
```

**Training and evaluation:**

```
num_steps = 1001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print('Initialized')

    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset: batch_data, tf_train_labels: batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions = session.run(
            [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (step % 50 == 0):
            print('Step {:4d} rate {:.4f} '.format(step, learning_rate.eval()), end='')
            accPred = accuracy(predictions, batch_labels)
            accValid = accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels)
            print('Loss {:2.3f}  Batch acc.: {:02.2f}%  Validation acc.: {:2.2f}%'.format(l,accPred,accValid))

    print('\nTest accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels)))
```

Loss freezes at 2.303 and validation accuracy at 10%:

```
Initialized
Step    0 rate 0.0500 Loss 4.903  Batch acc.: 18.75%  Validation acc.: 9.98%
Step   50 rate 0.0494 Loss 2.301  Batch acc.: 15.62%  Validation acc.: 10.00%
Step  100 rate 0.0489 Loss 2.302  Batch acc.: 12.50%  Validation acc.: 10.00%
Step  150 rate 0.0483 Loss 2.303  Batch acc.: 6.25%  Validation acc.: 10.00%
Step  200 rate 0.0478 Loss 2.306  Batch acc.: 0.00%  Validation acc.: 10.00%
Step  250 rate 0.0473 Loss 2.306  Batch acc.: 3.12%  Validation acc.: 10.00%
```

Please advice what could possibly go wrong?

Full [notebook](http://2) problem version at github. The problem cells are at the bottom.

Comment: Can you post your `tf.nn.*`-based model for comparison?

Comment: @GPhilo thanks, I updated the question woth the `tf.nn.*` code.

Comment: What you want to do in situations like this is reduce the problem to the smallest case that shows absurd behavior: 1 layer, width=1, num_steps=1, consts instead of your dataset, etc. You'll figure out the cause somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two weird things:

1. Your second model has a different architecture than the first one (in the first you have three dense layers, in the second just two)
2. possibly connected to 1., you're missing the linear layer at the end of the network (your output is `dense2`, which has a `relu` activation).

My idea is, then, that you forgot the last piece of your network:

```
dense_3 = tf.layers.dense(
            dense_2, 
            units=num_labels, 
            activation=None, #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed),
            bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0)
        )
return dense_3
```

Alternatively, remove the activation function from `dense_2`.

#### Update:

In the notebook, I see you define the convolutional+pool layers as follows:

```
conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    data, filters=depth, kernel_size=1, padding='SAME',
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed),
    bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
    name="Conv_1"
)
pool_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d( conv_1, pool_size=patch_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')
```

If I compare this to the way you defined the layers before:

```
def conv_relu_maxpool(inputs, kernel_shape, bias_shape, bias_init_v=0.0):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", shape = kernel_shape,
                              initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=seed))
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", shape = bias_shape,
                             initializer = tf.constant_initializer(bias_init_v))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, weights, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + biases)
    maxpool = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, [1,2,2,1], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
        
    return maxpool
conv_relu_maxpool(data, [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], [depth], 0.01)
```

I see that you have two errors:

1. You're using `1 x 1` kernels in the convolution instead of `patch_size x patch_size` (`kernel_size=1` in the call to `conv2d`)
2. You're doing maxpool on `5 x 5` windows instead of `2 x 2` (`pool_size=patch_size` in the call to `max_pooling2d`)

Please note, it is possible that there are more differences between the architectures, these are just those I saw immediately.

Comment: Thanks for having a look into my problem!
1. I added the 3rd dense layer in further attempts to increase accuracy, after the fork of the tf.layers "branch". The model performed with just two dense layers just as well.
2. Removed activation in the second dense layer, no change – exactly the same numbers in the output. Feels like I missed / mistyped? something generic..

Comment: @Serge could you please update the question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: I updated the question with the current code and a link to [my notebook](https://github.com/sergiks/udacity-deep-learning/blob/master/4_convolutions.ipynb) on github. The problem cells are the two at the bottom.

Comment: Thank You so much!
Indeed, I mixed the parameters meaning, which made me stuck for a few days.
Btw I did also update the code in the question along with adding the link.